# Android Studio gradle flavors not showing Build Variants correctly

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors, build-variant

I'm having trouble understanding build variants in Android studio. I created an empty project and added product flavors as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        }
        full {
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I synced the project with Gradle files and I only get a demo debut variant. As per my understanding, I should get,

- demoDebug
- demoRelease
- fullDebug
- fullRelease

Am I following anything wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try to manually sync your project with grade files. Use any of the below as per your Android Studio version:

`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`  [For older Android Studio version]

`File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` [For newer Android Studio versions]

Answer (score 1):

Specify the dimension for each flavor in the flavor block like this

```
flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension 'version'
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        }
        full {
            dimension 'version'
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that  its work for  me:
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files